# AngularJS $location service gets refreshed multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, digest

A function in my AngularJS controller are invoked multiple times (20+) for each route change. How can I avoid this?

I've made a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6rv078t/3/

Why is this happening, and what are the other digest related pitfalls that an AngularJS developer should be aware of?

```
   var myController = function ($scope, $location) {
    var _count = 0;
    $scope.locChangeCounter = {
        count: function (viewLocation) {
            console.log(' $location ... ' + $location);
            _count++;
            return _count;
        }
    };
    console.log(' just with in ctrl  ... ' + $location);
};
```

Comment: You're binding to `locChangeCounter.count()`, which returns a new value each time it's called. Angular's digest cycle will repeat until all bindings stop changing.

Comment: To add to the answer supplied by @AnthonyChu - the digest cycle will run until all bindings stop changing, but Angular will stop trying after a threshold (to avoid infinite looping). The default number of digest iterations is 10 for repeating changes. Your fiddle is hitting this (and the error is in the console).

Comment: If you provide your source that's causing the issues, we can likely help troubleshoot the non-fiddle-related issue.